# How do I make background Image on each division row from URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I need to display different background URL on each row base on the item in MySQL. I use php mySQL fetch array to get the item name and background URL. So far,  I was able to get the URL background and display in row by using CSS,  but every time I choose different item all division row get's overwritten by this new background. This result to have duplicate background.
I have attached of sample image where the background image of division row got overwritten and duplicate image.

[Duplicate Row Background][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxLOI.png

Snippet of Php fetch array to echo the division and the CSS id of Background Image.

```css
<style>
.blocks {
  display:table-row;
  
}
.block {
  display:table-cell;
  height:100px; 
}

#background-container { 
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  background: url(<?php echo  $bgurl; ?>) center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

```html
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
                    {
                        $pro_id = $row['pro_id'];
                        
                                $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = '$pro_id' ";
                                $query1 = mysqli_query($conn , $sql1);
                                while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) 
                                {

                                    $id = $row1['product_id'];
                                    $name = $row1['product_title'];
                                    $element = $row1['product_price'];
                                    $faction = $row1['product_description'];
                                    $picture = $row1['product_image'];
                                    $class = $row1['product_keywords'];
                                    $rarity = $row1['sales'];
                                    $bgurl = $row1['bgurl'];
                               
                            

                                echo 
                                '
                                
                                   <div class="container" id ="background-container">
                                
                                    <div class="row pt-2 pb-1" style="border-top: .5px  solid grey; border-bottom: .5px  solid grey;" >
                                    <div class="col-4" >
                                        <p class="squad1-title" >'.$bgurl.'</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-7">
                

                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="remove" >
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus-square removeitem" style="padding center" data-proid="'.$id.'" title="Remove"> </i>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                   </div>
                                ';
                                }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS
`#background-container` ---> Single tag in HTML

`.background-container` ---> Multiple tag in HTML

The problem is you overwrite the last one

Change

```html
#background-container { 
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  background: url(<?php echo  $bgurl; ?>) center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

<div class="container" id ="background-container">
```

By

```html
.background-container { 
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

<div class="container" class="background-container" style="background: url(<?php echo  $bgurl; ?>) center;">
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks this what I just did and it did have different image on each row division. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

ID's are used for one and only element in the page, you will need to switch to classes if you want to style multiple elements.

That being said, you can overwrite a css property by including it in the `style` property of an element

```
<?php
    echo `<div class="container" style="background-image: url(` . $bgurl . `)">`
    ...
?>
```